# Grip shifters on wrong side

Tags: mechanical

My new grip shifters were installed on the opposite sides than I'm used to.  Can I easily just switch them back to what I am used to?

Comment: Wouldn’t they turn in the wrong direction? Is there really a system where the right shifter is not for the rear derailleur?

Comment: @Michael correct.  Some grip shifters rotate the top-forward to change up, some are designed opposite, but the right hand shifter is always the rear derailleur at the cassette.  Frank might have to get used to twisting the other way.

Comment: I know the grip shift for the 3 speed nexus IGH (rental scheme near work) goes the opposite way to the 6 speed RD grip shift I've got. I still can't get used to it even though mine has been off the road for a while.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Did you buy your bike from a country with a different driving convention (drive on right vs. drive on left) as your country? I believe this is *why* they are swapped</s> (Edit: upon further reading I think only brakes should be swapped country-to-country), as to if you can switch them, [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16003/i-need-to-change-my-bike-from-uk-to-us-spec) (and probably your question is a duplicate) indicates no.